# Error when creating private network in hyperledger fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I was trying to create my own private network in ubuntu with hyperledger-fabric as mentioned in the documentation. When I was running the command `./byfn.sh up` I get the following error

> Error: error getting chaincode bytes: failed to calculate
>   dependencies: incomplete package:
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   Chaincode packaging on peer0.org1 has failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   ========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
>
> ERROR !!!! Test failed

Please help me solve this issue. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As there is not enough information provided.If it's a 2.0 network then the shim package and dependencies are not included in the images.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/tag/v2.0.0

So you have to manually install them. 
You can install them inside your CLI container by:

```
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim
```

and then run the peer chaincode installation command.(don't forget to import the path in your chaincode).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. The version of hyperledger fabric is 2.0